# Intersection and difference of multiple sets

Tags: python

I have multiple lists of "associations" as input:

```py
input1 = [
    ('id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4'),
    ('id5',),
    ('id6', 'id7', 'id8')
]
input2 = [
    ('id1', 'id2', 'id4'),
    ('id3',),
    ('id5',),
    ('id7', 'id6', 'id8')
]
input3 = [
    ('id1', 'id2'),
    ('id3', 'id4'),
    ('id5',),
    ('id8', 'id7', 'id6')
]
```

- Each input contains all the ids.
- Each id appears a single time in an input.
- The number of inputs can vary from 1 to 4.

---

I would like to process those inputs and generate something like this:

```py
assocs = {
    # never associated
    0: [
        ('id5',),
    ],
    # associated a single time
    1: [
        ('id1', 'id3'),
        ('id2', 'id3'),
    ],
    # associated twice
    2: [ # 
        ('id1', 'id4'),
        ('id2', 'id4'),
        ('id3', 'id4'),
    ],
    # associated everytime
    3: [
        ('id1', 'id2'),
        ('id6', 'id7', 'id8'),
    ]
}
```

I can somehow count the number of times that each association is encountered with:

```py
temp = defaultdict(int)

for ids in map(sorted, itertools.chain(input1, input2, input3)):
    for i in range(1, len(ids)+1):
        for comb in itertools.combinations(ids, i):
            temp[comb] += 1
```

But now I'm stuck with the following step, which would be cleaning the `temp` dict; not to mention that I'm not sure that I chose the right strategy in the first place.

Comment: Inverting the keys and values in the dict should not be too hard, but what do you mean with "cleaning")? Why is there just one 3-tuple in your desired output? I'd expect only pairs or all the tuples.

Comment: @tobias_k Thank you for the comment. The 3-tuple in the output is because that's an association that was found in all three inputs. The "cleaning" is because for eg., with the way I'm counting, the members of the 3-tuple will also be counted as 2-tuple and 1-tuple associations, which I want to remove in the final output.

Comment: Okay, I get why `('id6', 'id7')` or just `('id6',)` is not in group `3`, but why isn't there e.g. `('id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4')` in group `1`?

Comment: One reson for `('id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4')` not being in group 1 would be because `('id1', 'id2')` is in group 3, which results in splitting `('id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4')` in `('id1', 'id3', 'id4'), ('id2', 'id3', 'id4')`; but `('id3', 'id4')` is in group 2 so what's left in group 1 is `('id1', 'id3'), ('id1', 'id4'), ('id2', 'id3')`

Comment: I don't really understand with `('id5',)` is not in `3` because it's alone every time

Comment: Instead of chaining stuff, just make the inputs into a list.

Comment: @mozway `('id5',)` is in `0` instead of `3` because it appeared as a singleton in every input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is not fully clear to me, but it looks like you could generate the powersets of each tuple and count them, handling the loners specifically:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
from collections import Counter

inputs = [input1, input2, input3]

def powerset(iterable, min=2):
    # modified powerset recipe to yield at least pairs
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(min, len(s)+1))

cnt = Counter(tuple(sorted(s)) for lst in inputs for t in lst
              for s in (powerset(t) if len(t)>1 else (t,)))
out = {}
for k, c in cnt.items():
    out.setdefault(c if len(k)>1 else 0, []).append(k)
```

Output:

```
{0: [('id5',),
     ('id3',)],
 1: [('id1', 'id3'),
     ('id2', 'id3'),
     ('id1', 'id2', 'id3'),
     ('id1', 'id3', 'id4'),
     ('id2', 'id3', 'id4'),
     ('id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4')],
 2: [('id1', 'id4'),
     ('id2', 'id4'),
     ('id3', 'id4'),
     ('id1', 'id2', 'id4')],
 3: [('id1', 'id2'),
     ('id6', 'id7'),
     ('id6', 'id8'),
     ('id7', 'id8'),
     ('id6', 'id7', 'id8')]}
```

Different way of handling the loners:

```
cnt = Counter(tuple(sorted(s)) for lst in inputs for t in lst
              for s in powerset(t))

out = {0: [(x,) for x in set().union(*input1) - set().union(*cnt.keys())]}
for k, c in cnt.items():
    out.setdefault(c if len(k)>1 else 0, []).append(k)
```

output:

```
{0: [('id5',)],
 1: [('id1', 'id3'),
     ('id2', 'id3'),
     ('id1', 'id2', 'id3'),
     ('id1', 'id3', 'id4'),
     ('id2', 'id3', 'id4'),
     ('id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4')],
 2: [('id1', 'id4'),
     ('id2', 'id4'),
     ('id3', 'id4'),
     ('id1', 'id2', 'id4')],
 3: [('id1', 'id2'),
     ('id6', 'id7'),
     ('id6', 'id8'),
     ('id7', 'id8'),
     ('id6', 'id7', 'id8')]}
```

Comment: Thank you @mozmay, the second option is quite close to what I need to get, and I think I can see how to further process it to get my expected result.